# Continue an iteration in C++ until a specific iteration number in gdb

Tags: c++, gdb

I am using gdb-7.0.1 and I think I have detected a bug in a certain section of my code, which
has a `for` loop. The `for` loop looks like

```
for (int i=0 ; i< end ; ++i )
{
   //Code here.
}
```

Here `end` is a very large integer. The code does not crash at the first iteration, and seems to crash somewhere at iteration number `end/2`.

Since I want to understand the behaviour of the code at iteration number `end/2` , just `stepping` and `nexting` from `i=0` till I reach this iteration point, is unfeasible.

Is there a way to tell `gdb` to continue through a for loop till `i` gets the value `end/2` and then wait for the user to manually step through iteration number `end/2`?

I am using `gcc-4.5.2` on Ubuntu Linux

Comment: http://blog.vinceliu.com/2009/07/gdbs-conditional-breakpoints.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you set the breakpoint it'll give you a breakpoint number (for the moment, let's assume it's 1). You'll then make that breakpoint conditional, something like:

```
condition 1 i==end/2
```

Answer (score 6):

Here's a tutorial on [conditional breakpoints](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~gilpin/tutorial/#3.4) with gdb.

I'm guessing you didn't know the term for this, otherwise it would have been easy to google.

Comment: Another alternative is to `(gdb) ignore <break-point-number> end/2-1`

Answer (score 5):

You have to use conditional breakpoint. Here is more about it: http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~gilpin/tutorial/#3.4

And on SO: [How do I set a conditional breakpoint in gdb, when char* x points to a string whose value equals "hello"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4183871/conditional-breakpoint-in-gdb)

In your case (not tested):

```
break <line_number> if i==end/2
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to place an `if (i == (end/2 -1)) { Foo; }` in there then set a breakpoint at Foo, which would allow you to continue stepping from there.

Comment: +1 as this used to be my method until I found conditional breakpoints as @LuchianGrigore suggests.

Comment: Thanks yeah, I'm not sufficiently fluent in gdb to have picked up on it.  I figured it was a sufficiently generic solution to leave it up even in the face of the more poignant ones.

Answer (score 1):

If `end` is big (in the tens of thousands), then the conditional breakpoint solution can be very slow - gdb has to evaluate the condition each time round the loop. If this is a problem for you, then you can use this trick:

```
for (int i=0 ; i< end ; ++i )
{
   if (i == end/2)
      i %= end ; // This has no effect, but lets you set a breakpoint here
   //Code here.
}
```

I do this all the time :-)

Another solution is to set a skip-count on the breakpoint. I use gdb in a Qt environment, so I can't give you the gdb syntax. But it's faster than setting a condition.